# Passing options to camlp4 with ocamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, camlp4, ocamlfind

I'm using ocamlbuild's native support for ocamlfind to simplify my project's build process. 
File `foo.ml` relies on conditional compilation using camlp4's macros.  The `_tags` file contains the following:

```
<foo.ml>: package(camlp4.macro), syntax(camlp4o)
```

This works well, but I'm having trouble passing options to camlp4.  Without using the ocamlbuild+ocamlfind automation, the command line would be something as this:

```
camlp4o pa_macro.cmo -DFOO file.ml
```

But how can I pass camlp4 the `-DFOO` variable when using ocamlbuild+ocamlfind?  I feel there should be a simple command line option, instead of having to mess with `myocamlbuild.ml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You gonna mess with `myocamlbuild.ml`. There is no builtin rule to insert -ppopt so it is rather verbose, but simple.

`myocamlbuild.ml` :

```
open Ocamlbuild_plugin ;;
dispatch begin function
| After_rules ->
pflag ["ocaml";"compile";] "define" (fun s -> S [A"-ppopt"; A ("-D"^s)]);
pflag ["ocaml";"ocamldep";] "define" (fun s -> S [A"-ppopt"; A ("-D"^s)])
| _ -> ()
end;;
```

In `_tags`:

```
"foo.ml": syntax(camlp4o), package(camlp4.macro), define(FOO)
```

Comment: Note that if you pass `-pp` and `-ppopt` to ocamlfind then it seems to ignore the value of `-ppopt`. So I had to remove the "camlp4of" tags from my ocamlbuild `_tags` file and set `-pp` in my `myocamlbuild.ml` file.